# Windows 10 GridView style still looks like Windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I recently upgraded to windows 10 and noticed that while some controls in my app such as buttons, combo boxes, scroll bars changed, the GridView remained the same "bubbly" look as it had previously in windows 7.

How windows 10 apps look like with grid views (Control panel and Explorer):

[image: Control Panel]

[image: Explorer]

How my applications look when I use a generic GridView:

[image: How it looks now]

My question is how come these views are still the same as windows 7? Is there a way make it fit the Windows 10 theme while not changing anything for Windows 7 users?

Comment: That's WPF for you. Though it is odd that the scrollbar on this GridView didn't adopt the Windows 8 style - the scrollbars on my WPF apps do. I can't explain why.

Comment: It's probably not important but which .NET framework version are you targeting? Does anything change if you target 4.6?

Comment: WPF has it's own control rendering that does not rely on Win32 API. It tries to match the native control looks though.

Comment: @rshepp Changing to 4.6 has no effect

Answer (score 0):

WPF doesn't match Explorer 100%. It never has. You'll notice your Windows 7 app looks different from the Windows 7 Explorer. The colors are different and the mouse & keyboard behavior is slightly different. This is to be expected since Explorer isn't written in WPF. You have to be pretty nitpicky to notice the differences in Windows 7 though. I just happened to be picky, so I synced up the controls in my app. But... based on your screenshots, thats the WPF Aero skin. Windows 7 Explorer uses "way" different shades of blue.